# How do I fill in today's date in a computed property in Lightswitch?

Tags: c#, date, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a VS Lightswitch entity in which I would like to have a property that computes just the date (Is Computed) of the record creation. It is in C#.  I am unable to use the "Created" property that is automatically created in the entity because it does not report properly with any input mask.
How do I fill in today's date in a computed property in Lightswitch? Preferably the date only in mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: What do you mean by "input mask"? Dates are stored in an internal format, independent of any display format. Why can't you use the Created property?

Comment: I am trying to display the just the date from the "Created" property in an MS Access reports (and in Lightswitch desktop client) and no matter what I do with Input Mask at the report level or query level in access the complete date and time down to the second are displayed. In addition it is UTC time.

Comment: so your question is to do with displaying the date in a report, nothing to do with the way you store the date in Lightswitch at all. In both Lightswitch and Access, you should be able to set the format, so if you're having problems, you'll need to supply more info. Would be a help to know if you're using the Lightswitch Silverlight client or HTML for a start, but we'd also need more details of what you've done, and what happened.

Comment: Thank you.  The question remain, 
0
down vote
favorite

I have a VS Lightswitch entity in which I would like to have a property that computes just the date (Is Computed) of the record creation. It is in C#.

Comment: I appreciate your comments.  The question remains

I have a VS Lightswitch entity in which I would like to have a property that computes **just the date** (Is Computed) of the record creation. It is in C#..  Is it possible? I am using it in the desktop client and html.  The record is created in html.  If I need to handle the input mask for Access I will do that in separate question.  Thank you for your time on this.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're asking. If you want to store the created date, then you do **not** need a computed property. Just a plain date property on the entity will do. I still don't know what you mean by "input mask" as the created date will be read only, so no input going on

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  What I need is a property the will enter today's date (and just the date) at the time the record is created.  This would be done by adding a new property (field) in the lightswitch entity (table) and then selecting "computed".  The rest would be in some c# code.by selecting "Edit Method".   Thank you for sticking with me.

Comment: As I said before, you don't need a computed property for this. Add the field to the table as a regular field, then just populate it when the record is created (using the normal Creating/Created methods), and display it as you wish. You can save the data as datetime, and only show the date part. In the Silverlight client, there are checkboxes to specify which part of the datetime to show, so this is just a display setting, it doesn't affect the underlying data at all. Hope that's clear

Comment: A computed field is not a carrier of data in the sense that you can use it for other things than displaying data (that is computed into the desired format). If you want to populate a field in the table automatically, you should create a DateTime-type field in table and at creating the screen you set todays date in the Created-area (yourentity.yourdatetimefield = DateTime.Now).